# How to deploy MS bot to AWS as a serverless service

Tags: aws-lambda, botframework, chatbot

I developed a chat bot based on MS Botframework, but it seems that I have to create a rest server for it. but I prefer to deploy it as a serverless service, such as Amazon lambda, How can I achieve this? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how you could publish a bot as an AWS lambda, but Azure has the [Azure Bot Service](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/azure-bot-service/) which is similar:

> Azure Bot Service is powered by Microsoft Bot Framework and Azure Functions. By using Azure Functions, your bot will run in a serverless environment on Azure that will scale based on demand.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can deploy it to AWS. I currently have this use case, build a bot for Microsoft Teams app and deploy it to was lambda using https://github.com/vendia/serverless-express